# Add JSON string in JSON body

Tags: apex, json

Is there a way I can pass JSON string in the JSON body.

Example, Here is my JSON Body,

```
{"description":"Some Text","machinename":"add JSON","ipaddress":"192.128.0.0","version":"v3"}
```

In "machinename", I want to add this other JSON string so that it gets stored in the text field as JSON string ({ "id": "0684D0000004VgeTTE",  "success": true,    "errors": []}, something like below,

```
{"description":"Some Text","machinename":"{  "id": "0684D0000004VgeTTE", "success": true,    "errors": []}","ipaddress":"192.128.0.0","version":"v3"}
```

Every time I try to use snippet above, I believe its breaking because of quotation marks ("). Can I skip quotation mark to pass Json sting in JSON?

Comment: why can't you  send it as not json string, but json object, and then before saving it to text field serialize to json string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest:

```
String encoded = JSON.serialize('{"id": "0684D0000004VgeTTE", "success": true, "errors": []}');
```

that generates this string that is a valid JSON value:

```
"{\"id\": \"0684D0000004VgeTTE\", \"success\": true, \"errors\": []}"
```

that can be set as the "machinename" value. It keeps the logic in the JSON world.

Comment: Of course. That's a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do this, but `URLEncoding` it seems to work.

Try this:

```
String jsonStr = '{"id":"0684D0000004VgeTTE","success":true,"errors":[]}';
String encoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(jsonStr, 'UTF-8');
String jsonStr2 = '{"description":"Some Text","machinename":"' + encoded + '","ipaddress":"192.128.0.0","version":"v3"}';

Map<String,Object> obj = (Map<String,    Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonStr2);
System.debug(EncodingUtil.urlDecode((String)obj.get('machinename'), 'UTF-8'));
```

Of course it all depends what you are going to do with it on the other end, but this may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using single quotes instead of double quotes for the sub JSON worked for me.

```
    {  
       "description":"Some Text",
       "machinename":"
         {  
            'id':'0684D0000004VgeTTE',
            'success':true,
            'errors':[  

            ]
          }
       ",
      "ipaddress":"192.128.0.0",
      "version":"v3"
   }
```

[image: PostMan]

Comment: Try adding same json [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/), it looks like some extra chacters are added to the initial string, which would be hard to remove by JSON parsers.